# failed on last step, install ros indigo on raspbian jessie

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, jessie

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Direct dump of console output:

```
/opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/serialization.h:223:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_CREATE_SIMPLE_SERIALIZER_ARM’
     ROS_CREATE_SIMPLE_SERIALIZER_ARM(double);
     ^
c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs> for instructions.
CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/build.make:638: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/service_server_link.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/src/libros/service_server_link.cpp.o] Error 4
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/roscpp.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'roscpp':
  Command '['/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh', 'make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/roscpp && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh make -j4 -l4

Command failed, exiting.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274666/failed-on-last-step,-install-ros-indigo-on-raspbian-jessie/) by [clapfor](https://answers.ros.org/users/32452/clapfor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2017-10-31**:
What code are you using? It's really hard to debug your problem if you don't post the code that caused it. Try uploading it to a gist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> c++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)
> ```

Most likely your compiler is running out of memory, which makes the OS kill it.

Try to enable some swap for your Pi. That should make it work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-11-01**:
@gvdhoorn is right. Also try to compile everything with `-j2` option instead of default `-j4`.